Has macOS recently changed how it handles popup windows that open, print and close?
I'd implented a pop up window to print some javascript generated content, using code based on this old question.
The key bit of the code is
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=800,width=800');
mywindow.focus(); 
mywindow.print();
mywindow.close();

This was working, but I've just been given bug reports that it has stopped working on macOS, on both desktop Safari and Chrome.  I can't replicate the issue on a PC, so I assume it is an Apple-specific issue.  I don't have a desktop Mac to test on.
If you remove the mywindow.close(); then I'm told it works, but you have to close the window manually.
Is there a specific update which has stopped this working?  If so, what are the limitations it has added?

Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/t5wj6ras/1/. Make sure you're opening the window in response to a user action. If I didn't put it in a click event listener I got a "Popup window blocked" message.

What part of it isn't working, just the automatic close? When I run it I don't even see the popup window, just the Print dialogue.

From the bug reports, if I remove the window.close then everything works, but if the close is there then nothing happens.  Sounds almost like it is executing the close before running the print command.

Thanks for the jsfiddle - can you confirm what version of macOS and browser you were testing this on?  As I mentioned, my main problem is no desktop mac to test on.  It is being opened on click.

The latest version of Sonoma and Safari. Have you considered using BrowserStack for compatibility testing on other environments?

And latest Chrome.
